# "be reflective of" VS "reflect"

Tags: word-difference

> 1. The approach is **reflective of** the new services mindset: moving from just selling a product to selling a solution.
> 2. The approach **reflects** the new services mindset: moving from just selling a product to selling a solution.

Does 1) have the same meaning and implications as 2)? In English, we have other sets of similar words and phrases, such as "indicate" VS "be indicative of"; "typlify" VS"be typical of"; "suggest" VS "be suggestive of"...as far as I can recall.

Are these pairs exchangable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your examples, the verb and its related adjective-"*of*" construction mean exactly the same thing.

I imagine there are some situations where there would be some difference in nuance or implication between the pair (but I can't think of any offhand), and in these 3 cases, they are the same.

Most people would advise you to choose the less wordy option in your writing.

Comment: The main "nuance or implication " I would normally draw from the more verbose version is *this writer is a pompous ass, who has utterly failed in his intention to impress me*.